# Targeting elements without access to html

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I do not have access to the html in this document and the element I'm trying to select has an ID(coupon) that is shared with another element(selecting either element would be fine because they are identical).  So I was wandering if anyone could tell me how to go about selecting one of these without using the ID as the hook.

```
<div class="buttons">

   <div class="discount-module">
            <div id="coupon" class="content" style="display: none;">
              Enter your coupon code code here:&nbsp;
              <input type="text" name="coupon" value="">
              &nbsp;<a id="button-coupon" class="button"><span>Apply coupon</span></a>
            </div>
                                      <div id="vc-messages"></div>
          <div>
            <table class="radio">
                                <tbody><tr class="highlight">
                <td>                      <input type="radio" name="next" value="coupon" id="use_coupon">
                  </td>
                <td><label for="use_coupon">Use coupon Code</label></td>
              </tr>
                                                                 </tbody></table>
          </div>

          <div class="discount-module">
            <div id="coupon" class="content" style="display: none;">
              Enter your coupon code code here:&nbsp;
              <input type="text" name="coupon" value="">
              &nbsp;<a id="button-coupon" class="button"><span>Apply coupon</span></a>
            </div>
            <div id="voucher" class="content" style="display: none;">
              Enter your voucher code code here:&nbsp;
              <input type="text" name="voucher" value="">
              &nbsp;<a id="button-voucher" class="button"><span>Apply voucher</span></a>
            </div>
            <div id="reward" class="content" style="display: none;">
              Points to use (Max 0):&nbsp;
              <input type="text" name="reward" value="">
              &nbsp;<a id="button-reward" class="button"><span>Apply reward</span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Depends on what restrictions of the structure can be relied upon – something as simple as `.discount-module > div:first-child` might already work.

Comment: @CBroe unless I've misunderstood the question, I think OP is wanting to only select one of them, not both of them.

Comment: @James dunno … _“selecting either element would be fine”_, _“how to go about selecting one of these”_ – could mean either.

Comment: You can't use ID's mor ethan once on a page....there's your basic issue.

Comment: yes I would only like to select one

Comment: Well I didn't write the html it was generated by an opencart theme I do understand that you hsould only have 1 ID

Comment: Seems like everyone missed that the second .discount-module was actually a child of the first.  Probably my poor indenting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really shouldn't be duplicate IDs in HTML because it isn't valid, so I would avoid selecting with an ID if at all possible. Since it doesn't look like you can in this particular instance, however, here's one approach you can take.

1st coupon

```
.discount-module:first-of-type #coupon {
}
```

2nd coupon

```
.discount-module:nth-of-type(2) #coupon {
}
```

If you have a guarantee that the `#coupon` div is going to be the first div element in the `.discount-module` div. You can use something like

```
.discount-module:first-of-type > div:first-of-type
```

Comment: .discount-module:first-of-type > div:first-of-type worked! :D ty ty ty ty

Comment: .discount-module:first-child > div:first-child also worked :D